# How to make a user defined number of variables

Tags: python, loops, variables

I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to enter the specifications of a given amount of computers. I am then to use a formula to to calculate the overall 'value' of those computers using the specified specs.

However, my problem is I don't know how to create that many variables.

This is my code so far:

```
print("Best Computer Program")
int1=input("Enter an integer between 1 and 10000\n")

for x in range(int1)

    name=input("Enter your computer's name:\n")
    R=input("Enter the amount of RAM you want in GB: (1-128)\n")
    S=input("Enter the CPU speed of your computer in Hz: (1-4000)\n")
    D=input("Enter the disk drive space: (1-3000)\n")
    print()

    x
```

So this is the formula for calculating the value:

2 * R + 3 * S + D

But the problem is, I have to do it for however many computers the user wants to put in.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: or just re-use the same variables each time through the loop, and keep a running-sum total?

Comment: The thing is i need each variable to be seperate because I will be sorting later.

Comment: Do you need to keep all the values or just some 'best', according to some criteria?

Comment: I only need to keep the top two

Comment: @PeterWood sets remove duplicates but they do not sort them. OP could easily use the `sorted` function, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of tuples where the first item is the ranking. Sort the list and take the ones from the top. BTW, `input` gives strings which need to be converted to ints.

```
int1=int(input("Enter an integer between 1 and 10000\n"))

machines = []

for x in range(int1)

    name=input("Enter your computer's name:\n")
    R=int(input("Enter the amount of RAM you want in GB: (1-128)\n"))
    S=int(input("Enter the CPU speed of your computer in Hz: (1-4000)\n"))
    D=int(input("Enter the disk drive space: (1-3000)\n"))
    machines.append((2 * R + 3 * S + D, name, R, S D))

machines.sort(reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat more structured version:

```
def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= val) and (hi is None or val < hi):
                return val
        except ValueError:
            # not an integer; try again
            pass

class Computer:
    __slots__ = ["name", "ram", "speed", "disk"]

    @classmethod
    def from_prompt(cls):
        name  =   input("Enter your computer's name: ")
        ram   = get_int("Enter the amount of RAM you want in GB (1-128): ",      1,  129)
        speed = get_int("Enter the CPU speed of your computer in Hz (1-4000): ", 1, 4001)
        disk  = get_int("Enter the disk drive space in GB (1-3000): ",           1, 3001)
        return cls(name, ram, speed, disk)

    def __init__(self, name, ram, speed, disk):
        self.name  = name
        self.ram   = ram
        self.speed = speed
        self.disk  = disk

    def value(self):
        return 2 * self.ram + 3 * self.speed + self.disk

def main():
    num_machines = get_int("How many computers do you have? ", 0, 10000)
    machines = [Computer.from_prompt() for _ in range(num_machines)]
    machines.sort(key = lambda m: m.value(), reverse = True)
    # machines is now sorted from most- to least-valuable

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

While this can be solved in simple ways, we could also do this with [object-oriented programming](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html). We're going to create a Computer class, which holds the data about a given computer (an "instance" of the class), put all of the computers in a list, and then sort the list.

```
class Computer():
    # Classes are made up of attributes and functions.
    def __init__(self):
        # We initialize the instance by getting all of the information,
        # and store it as class attributes.
        self.name=input("Enter your computer's name:\n")
        self.ram=int(input("Enter the amount of RAM you want in GB: (1-128)\n"))
        self.cpu=int(input("Enter the CPU speed of your computer in Hz: (1-         4000)\n"))
        self.drive=int(input("Enter the disk drive space: (1-3000)\n"))
        # Now, we get the value (notice that this is its own function)
        self.get_value()

    def get_value(self):
        self.value = 2 * self.ram + 3 * self.cpu + self.drive

print("Best Computer Program\n")
num_computers = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 and 10000\n"))
computers_list = []
for _ in range(num_computers):
    # This is the point at which we create a new instance of the Computer
    # class.
    computers_list.append(Computer())

# Once we have all of the computers, we sort them.

# The 'lambda x: x.value' sorts the list by x.value
computers_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.value, reverse=True)

# Print the name and value of the first 2 computers.
print([(x.name, x.value) for x in computers_list[0:2]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

import this

It should help decide what solution best fits your needs :)